# jOOQ: Exclude column in update

Tags: java, jdbc, jooq

In this code I update a BOOKS row, trying not to set null the value of column TITLE because in `myPojo` is null and I don't want to override it (i.e. I attempt to exclude the column from the update):

```
        BooksRecord rec = new BooksRecord();
        rec.from(myPojo);               
        context.update(BOOKS)
           .set(rec)
           .set(BOOKS.TITLE, BOOKS.TITLE)
           .where(BOOKS.SK.eq(sk))
           .execute();
```

But this doesn't work, the TITLE column is set with null. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do it like this:

```java
BooksRecord rec = new BooksRecord();
rec.from(myPojo);
rec.reset(BOOKS.TITLE);
rec.update();
```

The call to [`Record.reset(Field)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Record.html#reset(org.jooq.Field)) resets the field's underlying [`Record.changed()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Record.html#changed(org.jooq.Field)) flag prior to any further action, such as [`Record.update()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/UpdatableRecord.html#update()), or when you copy the record's changed values into an `Update` statement like you did.